# How do you handle bad data when converting XLS to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, excel, import, sas, scale

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a Database inside an XLS file to MySQL. I have python code already working that can do this, but I'm not sure about the proper way to dynamically handle edge cases.

```
End Date  
04/12/2006 10:00:00  
04/12/2006 11:00:00  
4/12/2006 13:00:00 PM
```

For example I have one column of dates here. Obviously I can edit the cell here manually to match the other date format, but this isn't scalable if there are thousands of dates.

I can also write python code to handle this specific malformed date format, but it wouldn't work for other malformed dates.

```
  for c in range(0,col_names.ncols):
        #Ctype 3 means its a date. 1 is for Text
        if col_names.cell(r,c).ctype == 3:
            raw_time = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(col_names.cell(r,c).value, book.datemode)
            rowData.append(str(datetime.datetime(*raw_time)))
        else:

            if col_names.cell(r,c).value == 'NULL':
                rowData.append(None)
            elif "PM" in col_names.cell(r,c).value:
                col_names.cell(r,c).value = col_names.cell(r,c).replace("PM","")

            elif "AM" in col_names.cell(r,c).value:
                col_names.cell(r,c).value = col_names.cell(r,c).replace("AM","")

            else:
                rowData.append(col_names.cell(r,c).value)
```

I tried setting this column in Excel to be a Date format. All other cells except the last one converted fine.

Are there any programs or methods that will allow me override any date string in this column be the proper format?

Do other programs like SAS have a better ability to dynamically format input data?

Comment: You should show (the relevant part(s) of) your existing code. Note that this seems like a good spot to use MySQL [`LOAD DATA INTO TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I just added part of the code I used to parse out the Dates

Comment: There is no generic way to parse all possible data formats as date. The best solution would be to fix wherever the excel file is created - make date formats consistent.

Comment: Are you migrating one Excel 'data base' or for many ? If the source data is indeterminate you will want at least two teams to separately migrate the data and then compare.  If the cell values are indeed dates, removing formatting will reveal the Excel epochal date values.  Could be easier to remove the formatting and deal with the Excel date # to MySQL conversion later.  If some of the date values are Excel strings that are an indeterminate date representations you might have to deal with those one by one.

Comment: If you're importing it with SAS you can try ANYDTDTM but you may get unexpected behaviour as well. It would also require a CSV file to work a bit easier than an XLS file.

Comment: we recently added "drag and drop" feature that lets you load an excel file straight into any database you have a SAS Access engine for (the frontend scans all worksheets and extracts the first matching range then loads it into SAS via an approval process).  It's free to use in Dev environments:  https://datacontroller.io

Answer (score 0):

SAS does have a few different types of automated date reading functions.

Let's assume that your date is formatted exactly that way in Excel. Because this contains multiple datetime formats and the last format is being detected as a character, Excel converts some of the known dates into the number of days since Jan 1st 1900. SAS will read the raw values as characters.

```
End Date
38819.416666667
38819.458333333
4/12/2006 13:00:00 PM
```

We can use the `anydtdtm.` format to read in a variety of different types of datetime formats. If you find `/`, `:`, `-`, or , assume that it is a date Excel could not recognize as a date. Otherwise, adjust the Excel datetime to a SAS datetime (number of seconds since Jan 1st 1960) by reducing the days by the date of  Dec 30th 1899 and converting from days to seconds using the DHMS() function.  The reason to use Dec 30th instead of Jan 1st is because SAS and Excel disagree on whether to count from zero or one and because Excel mistakenly thinks 1900 was a leap year.

```
data want;
    set have;

    if(findc('end date'n, '/:- ') ) then end_datetime = input('end date'n, anydtdtm.);
        else end_datetime = dhms('end date'n + '30dec1899'd,0,0,0);

    format end_datetime datetime32.;
run;
```

This works for the three cases you gave. You'll need to test out other cases to see what happens. If Excel recognizes everything as a datetime, then you will not need to manually convert to a SAS datetime and `proc import` will handle everything.

Comment: Why the **magic** numbers? What is `-21916`?  Did you mean `+'30DEC1899'd`?  What is `86400`?  Did you mean `'24:00:00't`?  Pehaps you want to use `dhms('end date'n + '30dec1899'd,0,0,0)`?

Comment: Values came from this SUGI paper here on converting between Excel & SAS dates: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/068-29.pdf

Comment: User written papers are useful references, but you do need to take care that you understand them.  In this case the paper is using a poor coding style of using "magic" numbers.  At least with the paper there are pages of comments to give some context to help understand why those magic numbers were chosen.

Comment: Not quite right.  SAS stores time and datetime as seconds, but stores dates as days.  Excel stores dates as days, but it stores the timepart as fraction of day.  I updated your answer to fix that.